# Wht python package "mutmut" doesn't work with and command "mutmut results" returns error?

Tags: python, testing, mutation-testing, mutmut

Good day. I have a problem with mutmut package. I have installed "mutmut" and create config.cfg

```
[mutmut]
paths_to_mutate=some_path/to/folder
tests_dir=some_path/to/folder/tests
```

After I run "mutmut run" I have message, that there are 65 mutants need to be killed.
But when I run "*mutmut results*" I have the error "IndexError: tuple index out of range"
Some "mutmut show {number}" works for me, but some doesn't. Could you help me and explain where is the error and how to solve it?

I tried to rerun all mutation tests, but nothing work for me.

Comment: You should ask in the mutmut issue tracker

Comment: The author boxed is very responsive in the [mutmut issue tracker](https://github.com/boxed/mutmut/issues).

Comment: FWIW got the same error on Python 3.12, but not on Python 3.11. I am not going to investigate further, I was just curious what it finds in my project.